# Perform a String Search in Pascal

Tags: string, pascal

I have just started playing with Pascal using Dev-Pascal, and I want to know how to search for Strings. I have tried putting the String<> and AnsiCompareText to search for a user inputted string. How could I put a method to Search for a User inputted String in this [Inventory Program](http://pastebin.com/LjDC8Svw)?

For example, if I enter the information for 'Star Trek: The Search for Spock', then Search for 'Star Trek: The Search for Spock', It should return this movie, and all of it's information, the same as if you viewed all of the information. (Run the Program if this makes no sense)

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over all strings and simply compare strings to see if there is a match

Like most languages there are several ways to compare

- simply the = operator -> string should match exactly case sensistivity and all
- pos(substr,mystring)>0 checks if substr is anywhere in mystring
- ansicomparetext compares case insensitive.

Beware that dev-pascal uses an age old version of Free pascal that has been unsupported since 2005. I recommend you upgrade to a recent [Lazarus](http://lazarus.freepascal.org) which is based on a current version of the same (Free Pascal) compiler